# Visual Studio 11 Beta Prof. - Insufficient space on drive C

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a little SSD for my windows system and a big hard drive for all my data and installations.

When I try to install Visual Studio 11 on drive E I get the message:

"setup blocked"

Insufficent space on drive C.

It seems that the installer wants 6GB on drive C although I selected Drive E as installation path. Is there a way around?

Tried it with web- and ISO installer. Result is the same.

Answer (score -2):

Most of VS required files must be installed in Disk C, even you chose another partition.
A compromise may be helpful: ***choose the components that you really need***

Comment: I don't see the part where I can select the packages I want to install. The installer asks for the destination dir and on the second screen the error message apears. No chance to select the components I really need.